# Xamarin forms: How to add events in `XamForms.Controls.Calendar`?

Tags: xamarin.forms, calendar

I am using `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` for showing calendar in my application, I have added this package in all platforms.

Added following codes in xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <controls:Calendar  
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
            x:Name="calendar" 
            DateClicked="CurrentDate"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

In c#:

```
XamForms.Controls.Calendar calendar = new XamForms.Controls.Calendar()
            {
                WidthRequest = 300,
                HeightRequest = 300
            };
        }
        public async void CurrentDate(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var dateSelect = calendar.SelectedDate;
        }
```

I need to add events for dates in the calendar like school day, school mass or exam(Please see the screenshot added below). Is this possible in  `XamForms.Controls.Calendar`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin can add special dates: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/wiki/SpecialDates

```
calendar.SpecialDates = new List<SpecialDate>
{
    new SpecialDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3))
    {
        Selectable = true,
        BackgroundPattern = new BackgroundPattern(1)
        {
            Pattern = new List<Pattern>
            {
                new Pattern { WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.6f, Color = Color.Transparent },
                new Pattern{ WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.4f, Color = Color.Transparent, Text = "Mass", TextColor=Color.Black, TextSize=11, TextAlign=TextAlign.Middle},
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Is this effect what you want?

Comment: I tried the code, but on 30may, no text is showing.

Comment: This is what I want, it is working in android. But when I tested in windows it is not working. Do you know is this work in ios? I need this feature in android,ios and windows

Comment: @SreejithSree The doc I posted above has written: `Note: Only works in Android and iOS for now`

Comment: @SreejithSree Of course, `calendar.SpecialDates` is a list property. Add more items(SpecialDate) as you want.