# How to add school events to XamForms.Calendar.Control calendar?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, calendar

I would like to add school lessons, exams, etc to specific dates dynamically to my calendar (for example: right click the date to add the lesson/exam or select the date and having an add event button). Tried many ways for days but nothing were successful.
These are my C# codes:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using XamForms.Controls;

namespace ManageUni.Views.Navigation
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TimeTableView : ContentPage
    {
        public TimeTableView()
        {
            XamForms.Controls.Calendar calendar1 = new XamForms.Controls.Calendar
            {
                BorderColor = Color.Gray,
                BorderWidth = 3,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                StartDay = DayOfWeek.Sunday,
                StartDate = DateTime.Now
            };



            InitializeComponent();
        }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamForms.Controls;assembly=XamForms.Controls.Calendar" 
             x:Class="ManageUni.Views.Navigation.TimeTableView">
    <ContentPage.Content>



        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Órarend"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <controls:Calendar Padding="10,0,10,0"   
                           SelectedBorderWidth="4"   
                           DisabledBorderColor="Black"  
                           ShowNumberOfWeek="false"  
                           StartDay="Monday"  
                           TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"  
                           TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue"  
                           SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"  
                           SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"  
                           DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi, what is going wrong?

Comment: I tried special dates, I found how to add static events with them , but they didn't work at all. The codes did nothing. Then I found another one, but that one only colored the special dates.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried and what is going wrong in you question. it will help us to help you

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/156720/how-to-add-events-in-xamforms-controls-calendar This didn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290156/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-events-in-xamforms-controls-calendar This neither
https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/wiki/SpecialDates this one just coloured the dates but couldnt add events or texts

Comment: to start with, you have created a calendar control in both your XAML and in the code.  Pick one or the other, not both.  You have also not shown us your VM

Comment: Is there a sample application that you can download for that calendar? If so, get that working first. That should give you an idea of correct way to use it. Then start making chnages to it, to add what you want.

Comment: I deleted the c# calendar and the xaml calendar remained. I didn't find any working sample calendar yet on other websites, but Wendy"s solution is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DateClicked` event to simulate the add event. And then display a prompt to get the event to want to input. After that add the event into special datas. The last thing is to refresh.

Xaml:

```
 <Grid Margin="16,44,16,16">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Órarend"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <controls:Calendar
            x:Name="calendar"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="10,0,10,0"
            DateClicked="Calendar_DateClicked"
            DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"
            DisabledBorderColor="Black"
            SelectedBorderWidth="4"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
            ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
            SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
            StartDay="Monday"
            TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"
            TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
  async void Calendar_DateClicked(object sender, XamForms.Controls.DateTimeEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("SpecialEvent", "Create a new Event:");

        if (result == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var specialDates = calendar.SpecialDates;

        SpecialDate newDate = new SpecialDate(e.DateTime)
        {
            Selectable = true,
            BackgroundPattern = new BackgroundPattern(1)
            {
                Pattern = new List<Pattern>
                     {
                         new Pattern { WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.6f, Color = Color.Transparent },
                         new Pattern{ WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.4f, Color = Color.Transparent, Text = result, TextColor=Color.Black, TextSize=11, TextAlign=TextAlign.Middle},
                     }
            }
        };
        specialDates.Add(newDate);

        calendar.SpecialDates = specialDates;
        calendar.ForceRedraw();

    }
```

The model and view model you could get from the GitHub. https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to watch stackoverflow again since the day I asked for help. But I didn't solve the problem yet, because I need to connect it with a database and stuff I am not familiar with at all. But thanks for your answer, it is really helpful and I will implement it to my code!